# Default calculated amount blank on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator, pageload

I'm in need of a solution to show a calculated default number with a slider I'm using. The default slider value is set to "800". The calculated amount should then show as "99". However, the calculated amount doesn't show up until the user moves the slider - then, no issues. How can I set it up so that it already has the default calculated amount of "99" (based on "800") on page load?

Thanks so much!

```js
$(function() {
 $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
   range: "100px",
   min: 500,
   max: 1500, 
   value: 800,
   slide: function( event, ui ) {
     $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value ); //ui.value inside the event contains the slider value
     var x=$("#amount").val(); //this way you access slider value anywhere in your code
     var y=1.49;
     var a= Math.round(x*y/12);
     $("#product").html(a); 
   }
 });
   $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );

});


</script>


</head>
<body>

<p>

<input type="text" id="amount"  style="border:0
; font-size: 40px; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">

<label for="amount"  style="border:0
; font-size: 10px; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; "> / per month</label>

</p>
<div id="slider-range-max"></div>
<br/>


style="border:0; font-size: 40px; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">

$<span id="product"></span>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move your calculation out into a function, move your default value into a variable, and then do this:

```
function calculateResult(value) {
    return Math.round(value * 1.49 / 12);
}

$(function() {
 var defaultValue = 800;
 $("#product").html( calculateResult ( defaultValue ));
 $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
   range: "100px",
   min: 500,
   max: 1500, 
   value: defaultValue,
   slide: function( event, ui ) {
     var productValue = calculateResult( ui.value );
     $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value ); //ui.value inside the event contains the slider value
     $("#product").html(productValue); 
   }
 });
   $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );

});
```